# Translate web page using Python/Django

Tags: python, django, translation

Let's say I have a web page, and I want to translate it to another language.

One way to do it would be parse the DOM, and find out which strings need to be translated (like the title), use something like the Google Translate API, and show the result.

However, sending http requests to Google would make the application slow. Is there a better way to do it, especially through python itself?

Comment: Use the I8N feature of Django instead of relying on googles translation. Then you have full control over your translations instead. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install a machine translation system locally and then use that to translate the strings. One freely available system is Moses at http://www.statmt.org/moses/.

Please note that this system requires training data and training steps.